# invalid argumant: maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I try fetch data from database, and show in listView in flutter but i gor error

> invalid argumant: maximum call stack size exceeded

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vin/conections/company_name_con.dart';
import 'package:vin/models/company_name.dart';

class CompanyName extends StatefulWidget {
const CompanyName({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_CompanyNameState createState() => _CompanyNameState();
}

class _CompanyNameState extends State<CompanyName> {
late Future<List<CompanyNameModel>> cmm;

@override
void initState() {
  cmm = refreshCMM();
  super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
     title: const Text('chooz car'),
     centerTitle: true,
   ),
  body: RefreshIndicator(
    onRefresh: refreshCMM,
    child: FutureBuilder<List<CompanyNameModel>>(
        future: cmm,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<CompanyNameModel>? cmModel = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: cmModel?.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(cmModel![index].name),
                    trailing: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                    onTap: () {
                      log(cmModel[index].name);
                      log(cmModel[index].id.toString());

                      Navigator.pushNamed(
                        context,
                        '/car_type',
                        arguments: CompanyNameModel(
                          id: cmModel[index].id,
                          name: cmModel[index].name,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('${snapshot.error}');
          }
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }),
    ),
     );
 }
}
```

Comment: It sounds you have recursion some where.

Comment: Is that in this widget?

Comment: Looks like a problem in your refreshCMM function. It seems to be calling itself infinitely.